# CraftCMS 3: Template not found: dashboard

Tags: php, php-8.1, craftcms

I am trying to set up and existing CraftCMS 3 installation on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine with PHP8.1. The deprecation errors I can fix, no problem. DB imported, it's accessible, no biggie. All pages load so far, all good. With the exception of the dashboard (login works as expected). When I call `mydomain.com/admin/dashboard`, (in development mode) I get a

[image: 404 - dashboard template not found]

Now, I've taken a look into the templates/ folder. There never was a default template, only my custom ones. I created a `dashboard.twig`, but no change. The site is usable, but not configurable.

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: '…login works as expected'. 

So, once you login what's the URL? Seems like it does not work as expected…